# How to require modules in app/lib folder to rspec in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I moved my modules to

```
app/lib/parsers
```

folder.

Model classes responds to module methods, but when i try

```
rspec
I have issue

Failure/Error: include MainModule::Submodule

NameError:
uninitialized constant ModelName::MainModule

module in lib/parsers looks like this

Module Parsers
  Module Parser1
    def foo
    end
end
  Module Parser2

   def bar
   end
 end
end
```

first model includes first parser by that way

```
Class Model1 < ApplicationRecord
  include Parsers::Parser1
end
```

and the second one by the same way
What is the best way to require that modules in Rspec?

Comment: They should be auto-loaded without any additional steps, provided that FQN matches the path. Show some code (the module, at which path it resides and how you include it)

Comment: added some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to require that modules

Use rails' auto-loading mechanism. Put your `Parsers::Parser1` to `app/lib/parsers/parser1.rb` and `Parsers::Parser2` to `app/lib/parsers/parser2.rb`. See how module's full name mirrors where it's stored? That's how rails is able to find it.

Or you can require the file explicitly

```
# my_spec.rb
require_dependency Rails.root.join('app', 'lib', 'parsers')

RSpec.describe ...
```

Comment: the second one is helpful, thanks a lot. The first is not.

Comment: @zOs0: yet the first one IS the way you should be taking. The rails guide has a big red warning that "`require_dependency` should be rarely needed. Class names and file paths should match".